# Get exception error in C when trying to loop array

Tags: c

```
//Program Written By: Andre Chitsaz-zadeh
//Program Written On: 10/7/12
//Program calculates book cost for multiple book orders. Program written using multiple functions.`

#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

void inputData();

int main ()


{
    inputData();
}

void inputData()

{
    int i = 0;
    int costs[5];
    printf( "\nPlease enter five products costs.\n" );
    while(i < 5)
    {
    scanf("%d", costs[i]);
    i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Why do I get in exception error? The program looks simple enough! It compiles without problems but as soon as I input a number it says that "this program has stopped working". Thanks!!

Comment: You need to pass the element by reference.

Comment: Also, this kind of errors are spotted at compile time by any recent compiler by cranking the warnings level up enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", costs[i]);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%d", &costs[i]);// &cost[i] gets the address of the memory location you want to fill.
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
while(i < 5) {
    scanf("%d", &costs[i]);   
    i = i + 1;
}
```

a little typo I assume, anyway you need to provide the address of the element of the array you want to scan the integer into.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's this line:

```
scanf("%d", costs[i]);
```

It should be:

```
scanf("%d", &costs[i]);
```

`scanf` needs a pointer to the variable in which it should put the read result.

---

This looks like a homework question, judging by the comment about the program have multiple functions.  If functions are new, then pointers have probably not been covered yet.   In that case, read my explanation as:

`scanf` needs a `&` before the variable in which it should put the read result.  You'll learn why in a few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to change you `scanf` line to

```
scanf("%d", &costs[i]);
```

You need to pass the address of the int to have user input written to it.  Your current code passes the value of `costs[i]`.  This is undefined so will point to an unpredictable, and probably not writeable, location in memory.